# Using bash and ssh how do I write a log locally from a remote host

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, tail, head

I am trying to get data from a file from a remote host and write to a log file locally using SSH. The log file tmp_results.log is not being created. Any ideas where I 'm going wrong please?

```
 ( ssh -nq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i $PEM_PATH/$PEM_FILE $USER@${host} -p $REMOTE_PORT \
tail -n 6  $REMOTE_HOME/data/result.jtl | >> $SCRIPT_DIR/$project/tmp_results.log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems a little bit confused by using pipes and redirections of filedescriptors.

Here you write in your logfile:

```
ssh -nq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i $PEM_PATH/$PEM_FILE $USER@${host} -p $REMOTE_PORT \
tail -n 6  $REMOTE_HOME/data/result.jtl > $SCRIPT_DIR/$project/tmp_results.log
```

If you want to append the output on existing file just use:

```
ssh -nq -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
-i $PEM_PATH/$PEM_FILE $USER@${host} -p $REMOTE_PORT \
tail -n 6  $REMOTE_HOME/data/result.jtl >> $SCRIPT_DIR/$project/tmp_results.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!